# Python readline() inside function skips second line in file

Tags: python, function, loops, readline

I'm an absolute beginner in the programming field. I'm doing some exercises from a book and there's something I don't understand.
I'm using a readline() command inside a function and then starting a for loop in main() to find the largest number in a file. The file has a list of numbers in each line: the largest number is in the second line, but for some reason the program skips the second line (which contains the largest number). This is the code:

```
def reader(filename):
    nums = filename.readline()
    return(nums)

def main():
    filename = open("numbers.txt", 'r')
    largest = reader(filename)
    for line in filename:
        number = reader(filename)
        if number > largest:
            largest = number

    print("The largest number is:", largest)

main()
```

But when I put the readline() in the main() function and change the parameter inside the loop things work fine:

```
def helper(filename):

    nums = filename
    return(nums)

def main():

    filename = open("numbers.txt", 'r')
    largest = helper(filename.readline())
    for line in filename:
        number = helper(line)
        if number > largest:
            largest = number

    print("The largest number is:", largest)

main()
```

There's obviously something that I'm missing but I don't know exactly what it is.

Comment: Why do you need the readline to happen in a separate function? In the second case you're literally reading the line from the file, and passing it to a function which immediately returns it.

Comment: You call a function with a `return` statement. You may find an answer in the `yield` statement.

Comment: I was doing an exercise on modularisation and encapsulation (this is a much simpler version, of course) and something worked one way and not the other, and I couldn't understand why (now I do). The separate function in this version is not necessary, obviously, but it's part of the problem as I encountered it.

Comment: Your `helper/reader()` function is not helping, it's obfuscating the fact that you're trying to simultaneously read from the file-object at two different points in the for-loop. Hence, odd lines go the first one (`for line in filename:`), even lines to the second (the `helper/reader()` call). Don't do that.

Comment: By the way (not crucial, but still important to use the right terms): in your code `filename` is not a filename, but a [***file object***](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), which is itself an iterator (which implicitly calls `readline()`). To avoid the confusion you got from misnaming it, typically in Python we would write `f = open("numbers.txt", 'r')` or more modern idiom `with open("numbers.txt", 'r') as f:`

Answer (score 2):

`for line in filename:` reads each line in the file.

Calling `readline()` while inside such a loop, as you do in the first code sample, will cause the `for` loop to miss that line, as it was consumed by `readline()` and is no longer available to be consumed by the `for` loop.

The second code sample does not have this problem, because you are no longer calling `readline()` inside of a `for line in file:` loop.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It is confusing when you don't know why something doesn't work. But is equally confusing when something works and you don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    filename = open("numbers.txt", 'r')
    largest = -1
    for line in filename:
        if int(line) > int(largest):
            largest = line


    print("The largest number is:", largest)

main()
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21342393)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan How is this a "me too!" comment or a new question? It should include more explanation, but it appears to be an actual attempt to answer the question. I'm voting "looks OK" on this one.